# Creation of UPGCUST fails without any Error during PeopleSoft Application upgrade 9.1 to 9.2

Tags: peoplesoft

We are in a process of upgrading our Application from 9.1 to 9.2, while we have already upgraded our tools release to 8.55 (from 8.51). We are facing a weird issue where the CA fails at the step "Creating the UPGCUST Project" without giving any error. In the log file we can see that the "Records Application Upgrade Customized Project Generation started" time, but nothing is logged after that. The following is the command being used:

```
pside.exe -CT ORACLE -CS  -CD DBname -CO VP1 -CP * -CI people -CW *  -PJRCUST UPGCUST  -OBJ All -LF D:\temp\UPGCUST_compare.log -HIDE -QUIET -SS NO -SN NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we resolved the issue. We ran the SYSAUDIT report, which was was apparently not clean. Hence, certain records were causing the App D to close abruptly. After cleaning the SYSAUDIT, the UPGCUST got created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the command in a command prompt?

In case it's a glitch in the CA: 
you could also execute the steps manually in the App Designer.